# Advice needed: low-level signal at 10m distance

Tags: audio, usb, low-level

audio noob here. Please be gentle.

I'm required to design a box with a jack for a headset and connector for an unknown cable going to a Windows desktop PC.

Headset has the standard 3.5mm plug for microphone, r speaker, l speaker, and ground.

Intention is there's a user at desktop PC who will communicate with user of the headset.

Questions:

1) the box is only pass-through. what's the best cable I can use to pass these low-level signals between headset and Windows desktop PC? distance is 10-15 meters.

2) at desktop PC side, what's the best hardware I can use so Windows desktop PC can receive/process these signals? I'm thinking USB link to PC but not sure what's available out there.

TIA!

Comment: Note that this question has been flagged for being off topic. Stack Overflow is specifically for asking questions about **programming**, not audio hardware. You'll probably have more luck on [Sound](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @ConorNeilson: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ would seem like a more likely site; the OP is *designing* hardware that cares about analog signals.  Although it's kind of vague, with no details about signal levels and frequency ranges; the built-in sound hardware on nice motherboards is very good these days, like -110 or -120dB SnR, and supporting high sample rates if it's not just human-hearing audio you want to handle.

Comment: Cheers for the better advice @PeterCordes